# how to add modified plugin to my app? how to give path?

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, dropdown

I modified the plugin `dropdown_formfield` and gave the name `dropdown_formfield-hijacked.dart`. Now I cant give a path to my dependency. it is located at the same level `pubspec.yaml` in my app.

```
dependencies:
  dropdown-formfield:
     path: 'what is the path'?
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you might have a folder called `projects` where you keep your source.

You might have two projects:

> /projects/some_project
>
> /projects/dropdown_formfield

In the former, you refer to the latter as:

```
    dropdown_formfield
      path: ../dropdown_formfield
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but my problem is this: modified dropdown-formfield is renamed and stored in my_project in the same level with pubspec.yaml. how can i give path to that from pubspec?

Comment: You can't. Simply move it to its own folder and create another project for it. You'll have two projects in sibling folders. One to continue to modify and test the other project and one to continue developing your project.